# Implementing Pettitt test in R

Tags: r, time-series, heteroscedasticity

I'm trying to implement Pettitt test in R following papers like this [pdf](http://www.ias.ac.in/jess/forthcoming/JESS-D-13-00049.pdf) (pp. 5 & 6), or this [pdf](http://www.igu.in/17-3/paper-2.pdf). But, I'm misunderstanding something, because having tested it with some data, I think that output is not correct.

Here is the code:

```
pettitt <- function(x, alpha=0.99) {
# Pettitt AN. 1979 A non-parametric approach to the change point detection.
# x is a vector
# alpha, integer, level of significance
x <- na.omit(x)
o <- rank(x)
s <- c()
L <- length(x)
for (i in 1:(L-1)) {
      s <- c(s, 2*(colSums(as.matrix(o[1:i]))) - (i*(L+1)) )
}
vc <- sqrt((-1) * log(alpha) * (L^3 + L^2)/6)
output <- list(abs(s), vc)
return(output)
}
```

Testing with `larain` and `tempdub` dataset from `TSA package`:

```
library(TSA)
data(larain)
data(tempdub)
pettitt(larain)
[[1]]
  [1]  78 118 180  76  30  30 144  90 124 148 224 334 314 298 362 444 356 334
 [19] 300 302 194 121  83  55  45  57  25  95 175 195 193 287 181 231 175 213
 [37] 301 331 421 345 392 322 282 354 372 274 194 130 188 248 175  97  85 153
 [55] 105 171 181 189 245 297 401 375 449 557 467 551 594 576 602 490 406 354
 [73] 262 266 362 248 244 214 208 200 247 147  89  13   9  15  97   5   9  83
 [91]   3  95 123  63  31  12  44   6  48  34  72 108 208 164 170 282 214 148
[109] 202 140 104   6 102  86

[[2]]
[1] 50.69224

> max(pettitt(larain)[[1]])
[1] 602

pettitt(tempdub)
[[1]]
  [1]  83 161 226 235 164  60  80 169 220 219 188  74  57 177 266 281 228 147
 [19]  19  82 125 140 102  41 100 197 235 254 233 141   1  97 144 153 112  26
 [37]  73 206 255 258 235 137  28  49  98 101  46  29 149 252 281 274 247 160
 [55]  43  70 115 126  79  22 157 248 317 328 287 224  96  27  86  79  27  82
 [73] 225 348 407 406 351 256 125  10  58  77  32  61 200 314 381 386 353 216
 [91] 124  40  35  70  35  36 173 302 365 386 321 242 131  10  51  38  19 146
[109] 241 319 342 359 330 223  89  45 113 144 111   2 123 228 280 275 250 177
[127]  34  50  89 102  59  22 131 248 334 359 302 198  73  46  83 100  73

[[2]]
[1] 70.96777

> max(pettitt(tempdub)[[1]])
[1] 407
```

I don't know if I lost something in pettitt test or there are error in my code.

Comment: I don't think this question needs to be migrated to SO necessarily, b/c the OP wants to know if his code matches the how the test is supposed to work. Ie, the OP is asking about the *ideas* primarily. It's a subtle distinction, & admittedly, someone will have to know both R & the Pettitt test to answer, but I think this is a stats question, not a coding question.

Comment: @gung OK, I won't vote to close, but I must ask Raz_Lobo: please explain how you know your code is giving incorrect output. (Warning to readers: the two pdf links in the question appear to have very long load times.)

Comment: Raz_Lobo, your second link does not load (at least not for me) and the formulas in the first one on pp 5 and 6 are clearly incorrect. For a more accurate account of the Pettitt test (published in a reputable journal), please see Equation 5 in http://www.stat.purdue.edu/~zhanghao/ASS/Reference%20Papers/Temporal%20and%20Spatial%20variability%20of%20annual%20water%20level.pdf.

Comment: @whuber I see these other equation you appoint early in other paper, but, really, I don't know how to implement it, where is a max in a oscilating function between -1 < x < 1? You can see the equations I implemented in this other paper: "http://www.homogenisation.org/files/private/WG1/Bibliography/Applications/Applications (P-S)/sahin_etal_2010.pdf" (I think that this is reputable, only links other because them reflects level of significance equation) In order to check code is giving incorrect output, you can see  table IX in the paper I link.

Comment: Are you purely interested in implementing the Pettitt test in R or do you have some applications in mind, also? If your aim is to produce an implementation of the test, could you consider getting the original article from JSTOR (http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2346729?uid=2129&uid=2&uid=70&uid=4&sid=21102620240847) which would probably describe the test in more details. If you are more interested in applying the test in some research setting, have you checked the cpm package that contains an implementation of the Mann-Whitney test (similar to Pettitt test) using a simulation approach?

Comment: @JTT I'm trying to apply Sahin et al metodology to my own data, then yes, I interested in implement Pettitt test and, yes, in R. Finally, a friend I ask, can found original article: [link] ftp://oceane.obs-vlfr.fr/pub/irisson/papers/Pettitt1979-A%20non-parametric%20approach%20to%20the%20change-point%20problem00.pdf I think that, with original article, I'll could implement it. At respect of cpm package, I tryed it but I can't compile it.

Comment: Not sure if it helps but there is a pettit.test function in the trend package. It is set-up (I think) for continuous data using a p.value of 0.05 to indicate significance. Also did anyone figure out how to calculate the critical value for the function developed by @Raz_Lobo above?

Answer (score 1):

After read carefully Pettitt paper, I can understand the method and check my code.

Pettitt starts with a general method expresed:

$$U_{t,T} = \sum_{i=1}^{t} \sum_{j=t+1}^{T} D_{ij}$$

where $D_{ij} = sign(X_i - X_j)$

Then Pettitt follows expressing a test for discrete Bernoulli and Binomial data and two variants for continuos data.

For discrete test, he use $U_{t,T} = T \cdot (S_t - \frac{tS_t}{T})$, where $S_t = \sum_{1}^{T} X_j$, $S_T = \sum_{1}^{T} X_j$ and $X_j$ is eval function expresed like Bernoulli serie where values are 0 or 1.

For continuos test, he use:

1. $U_{t,T} = 2 \cdot W_t - t(T+1)$, when $W_t=\sum R_j$ and $R_j$ are the rank or the data. (There is a variation when ties exists.)
2. $U_{t,T} = U_{t-1,T} + V_{t,T}$, with $t=2,\dots,T$ and $V_{t,T} = \sum_{j=1}^{T} sign(X_t - X_j)$.

Then, my original code are variant 1 for continuos test and results are correct, except for guessing critical values in Pettitt series results.

I calculate these critical values solving $K_T$ from 
$P_{OA} = 2e^{(\frac{-6{K_{T}}^2}{T^3+T^2})}$, but although $P_{OA}$ is solved correctly, the critical value is not. Why? Actually, I don't know and I can't reach others papers where shows how to calculate table expresed in, for example, Sahin et al paper (link in previous comments).

So that, I change my function code in order to include all variants and $P_{OA}$ calcul. Here are:

```
<!-- language: lang-R -->
pettitt<-function(x,alpha=0.01,method=c("discrete","continuos"),
                  alternative=c("rank","variation")) {
   # Pettitt AN. 1979 A non-parametric approach to the change point detection.
   # (Sección 2.3)
   #
   # x is a numeric vector
   # alpha is a integer
   x<-na.omit(x)
   orden<-rank(x)
   T<-length(x)
   method<-match.arg(method)
   alternative<-match.arg(alternative)
   #
   U.t.T<-c()
   V.i.T<-c()
   P.o.a<-NULL
   P.o.a.p<-NULL
   P.o.a.n<-NULL
   k.T<-NULL
   k.T.p<-NULL
   k.T.n<-NULL
   #
   if (!is.numeric(x))
      stop("'x' must be a numeric vector)
   #
   # Discrete values
   if (method == "discrete") {
      x.j<-sign(x)
      x.j[which(x.j==-1)]<-0
      S.T<-sum(x.j)
      for (i in 1:T) {
        S.t<-sum(x.j[1:i])
        U.t.T<-c(U.t.T,
           T*(S.t-(i*S.T/T)))
      }
      k.T<-max(abs(U.t.T))
      k.T.p<-max(U.t.T)
      k.T.n<-min(U.t.T)
      P.o.a<-exp((-2*k.T.p^2)/(S.T*(T^2-T*S.T)))
      critical<-sqrt((log(alpha)*(S.T*(T^2-T*S.T)))/-2)
   }
   #
   # Continuos value.
   if (method == "continuos" & alternative == "rank") {
      TIES<-length(unique(x)) < T
      if (!TIES) { 
        for (i in 1:T) {
           U.t.T<-c(U.t.T,
              2*(colSums(as.matrix(orden[1:i])))
                 -(i*(T+1))
           )
         }
      } else {
        frequency<-as.vector(table(x))
        total.frequency<-sum(frequency)
        for (i in 1:length(frequency)) {
           U.t.T<-c(U.t.T,
              1-(total.frequency*(frequency[i]^2-1))/(T*(T^2-1))
           )
        }
      }
      k.T<-max(abs(U.t.T))
      P.o.a<-2*exp((-6*k.T^2)/(T^3+T^2))
      critical<-sqrt((log(alpha/2)*(T^3+T^2))/-6)
   }
   if (method == "continuos" & alternativa == "variation") {
      V.i.T<-matrix(rep(NA,T^2),ncol=T)
      for (i in 1:T) {
        for (j in 1:T) {
           V.i.T[j,i]<-sign(x[i]-x[j])
        }
        if (i==1) {
           U.t.T<-sum(V.i.T[,i],na.rm=T)
        } else {
           U.t.T<-c(U.t.T,
              U.t.T[(i-1)]+sum(V.i.T[,i],na.rm=T)
           )
        }
      }
      V.i.T<-colSums(V.i.T,na.rm=T)
      k.T.p<-max(U.t.T)
      k.T.n<-min(U.t.T)
      k.T<-max(abs(U.t.T))
      P.o.a.p<-exp((-6*k.T.p^2)/(T^3+T^2))
      P.o.a.n<-exp((-6*k.T.n^2)/(T^3+T^2))
      P.o.a<-2*exp((-6*k.T^2)/(T^3+T^2))
      critical<-sqrt((log(alpha/2)*(T^3+T^2))/-6)
   }
   output<-list(U.t.T,V.i.T,P.o.a,P.o.a.p,P.o.a.n,k.T,k.T.p,k.T.n,critical)
   return(output)
}
```

If anyone knows how calcul critical values are welcome.

So many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sahin & Cigizoglu uses small sample simulation to calculate critical values for $U_t$ (table IX); the formula you use is an approximation (Pettit's equation 2.12) to an asymptotic approximation to the p-value obtained from the [Kolmogorov distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test#Kolmogorov_distribution) ... yes, that's two levels of approximation.

For large $n$, the asymptotic approximation will work well, and for p-values that are not large, the second approximation should work quite well (but is unnecessary)

Inverting that approximation to the approximation may not be a very accurate way to get critical values, however -- I can't see why you'd need to generate critical values, though, when you have formulas for p-values.